# Accuracy computation of clustering in 2x3 matrix

Tags: clustering

What are the approach to calculate the accuracy of K-Means clustering analysis? Currently, the target variable is binary with K defined as 3.

```
        c1      c2     c3         
       1000    800    1200       
       20       5      360
```

with First Row: No & 
Second Row: Yes

Would appreciate some inputs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This not accuracy.

But this is known as the [**contingency table**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table).

You obtain it simply by *counting*.